# Parameter 2: The parameter name is invalid.when searching in cyirilic?

Tags: c#, android, sql, listview

I am developing an android application and I have a listview, with an EditText on top and a search button, in which I want to display some rows (companies) based on the filter criteria in the edittext. When I search for a specific company and I write the name in English, I get the needed results, but when I try to search for a company in cyrilic (in my case bulgarian), I get the following error:

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. 
> Parameter 2: The parameter name is invalid.

I believe the error is a bit misleading, since I am more than sure that the parameter name is the same one as the one in the SP. Here's a small part of the code:

```
private void InitCommandCollection()
{
    this._commandCollection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand[1];
    this._commandCollection[0] = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    this._commandCollection[0].CommandTimeout = GS.CommandTimeout;
    this._commandCollection[0].Connection = this.Connection;
    this._commandCollection[0].CommandText = "dbo.rsp_ContragentInfo_ByContragentShortName";
    this._commandCollection[0].CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    this._commandCollection[0].Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ShortName", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 16, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problems could be because of the varchar and you should probably use nvarchar

> nvarchar stores UNICODE data. If you have requirements to store
>   UNICODE or multilingual data, nvarchar is the choice. Varchar stores
>   ASCII data and should be your data type of choice for normal use.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will keep that in mind next time